# Display error with reputation chart on mobile

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, mobile-web

I just noticed this display bug on mobile view (Safari - iOS8 on iPhone 6) in my profile at the reputation chart. I tried so search for other reports but I didn't find anything, resulting me in reporting this bug.

[image]

Comment: Well, no one is working on the mobile version of SE anymore. I'm having a similar problem on Windows 10.